# Why does CAST(SYSDATE AS CHAR) not provide the same detail as TO_CHAR()?

Tags: oracle, casting, sysdate

I prefer to use functions which are usable across platforms, when possible.  So to get the current time, I tried:

```
CAST(SYSDATE AS CHAR(19))
```

...but got just '07-JUL-14'.  If I use Oracle's native function:

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss')
```

...I get all the detail I expect.  [The doc page for `SYSDATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm) says that the value returns is a date/time.  So why doesn't `CAST(SYSDATE AS CHAR)` return a date/time value?

I'm tempted to self-answer with "Oracle, by default, truncates dates when casting them to CHAR or VARCHAR," but I have limited Oracle experience so I'll leave the question open in case any experts can give a better answer.  For example, is there some way to change this behavior?  Is there some historical reason that Oracle decided to have `CAST` destroy information in this way?

Comment: I think `cast` uses the current NLS settings to convert the date to a character representation. I would think that if you change your NLS_DATE_FORMAT, cast will return a different character string

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, nope that don't work. Pretty weird. I believe there must be something wrong w.r.t cast(date as char/varchar) and so always see people use to_char instead.

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/32592

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cast` uses the format defined in `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to convert the `DATE` into a string:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jul 16 00:39:11 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Jul 16 2014 00:38:39 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing optio

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select cast(sysdate as varchar(20)) as the_date from dual;

THE_DATE
--------------------
2014-07-16 00:39:27

SQL>
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.

SQL> select cast(sysdate as varchar(20)) as the_date from dual;

THE_DATE
--------------------
16.07.2014 00:39

SQL>
```